# Input bindings and geo distributed cosmosdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

I have a ComsosDB that is distributing read copies to muliple regions.  I have multiple instances of some Azure functions in each of those regions also that have input bindings to the CosmosDB and I want to ensure they talk to the local replication of the Cosmos database, instead of back across the world to the write location.
I see that the SDK allows for a PreferredLocations to be set, does the input binding handle this for me through some auto discovery, or is this something I can set in my connection string perhaps?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.table.tableconnectionpolicy.preferredlocations?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_CosmosDB_Table_TableConnectionPolicy_PreferredLocations

I could manually input the AccountEndpoint to the local region for each function similar to the REST api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api#rest  but I was hoping the function binding handled this automatically or with some hints in case of failovers.

Comment: You linked the Tables SDK, are you trying to access a Cosmos DB Tables account? or a SQL account?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Account

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of the `DocumentClient` instance (that's the place where you could change the `ConnectionPolicy`) is [not exposed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Services/CosmosDBService.cs#L21) in the Functions integration.

In this case you could create your own instance of the `DocumentClient` in the Function and setup your configuration there. As a performance advice, instead of creating the `DocumentClient` inside the `Run` function code, create it as a static variable so it gets reused in-between function executions instead of re-created.

Sample on how to maintain a static reusable `DocumentClient`

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;

static DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(
new Uri("https://<your-account>.documents.azure.com:443/"), 
"<your-key>",
new ConnectionPolicy(){
    // TODO: set your preferences here
});

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var document = await client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("<your-db>","<your-collection>","<some-id>"));

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, document.Resource.Id);
}
```

Comment: So is the input binding not attempting to use the local/closest replica of the cosmosdb automatically?

We are using nodejs for our functions, not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the NodeJS SDK but based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-sql-api#nodejs-javascript-and-python-sdks), `In this case, the SDK will automatically direct both reads and writes to the current write region.` unless the preferred locations are specified.